# Autorun Script on Boot with Inputs?

Tags: debian, openvpn

I would like to run OpenVPN on boot of a Debian machine which also auto fills the server login and password. I've been having to run after booting through SSH constantly and detaching with tux but would rather take all the hassle out.

Here is a paste of the SSH log so you can get an idea of the commands and info that is needed to run:

```
/etc/openvpn$ sudo openvpn server.vpn.com.tcp443.ovpn
Tue Aug 15 18:54:42 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.4 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 26 2017
Tue Aug 15 18:54:42 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: ******************
Enter Auth Password: ********
```

Any help that can be given is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your setup to use public keys instead of passwords. Examples are provided in [OpenVPN HOWTO](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki).

If you wish to keep your current setup you can provide username and password in file using `--auth-user-pass [up]` option as explained in [documentation](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html):

> **--auth-user-pass [up]**
>
> Authenticate with server using username/password. up is a file containing username/password on 2 lines (Note: OpenVPN will only read passwords from a file if it has been built with the --enable-password-save configure option, or on Windows by defining ENABLE_PASSWORD_SAVE in config-win32.h).
>
> If up is omitted, username/password will be prompted from the console.
>
> The server configuration must specify an --auth-user-pass-verify script to verify the username/password provided by the client.

If you running systemd on your machine, you should be starting the OpenVPN instance by `systemctl start openvpn@NAME.service` (as root/with sudo). You need to have the configuration file in `/etc/openvpn/NAME.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you running on Debian with SystemD you need to define new service with parameter of `wanted by`in your using target therefor service will be start on boot . If you are using SystemV write your scripts in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` .

For systemD first copy a system service to have template for configure new service :

```
 $ cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service /etc/system/systemd/myservice.service
 $ vim /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service
```

After that you need to update `ExecStart` parameter with your openvpn script ( your openvpn script is simple such as `cat user-pass-file | openvpn config.ovp` which put user-pass in file ) . Also add `WantedBy=graphical.target` which let you service start at graphical target . after that insert following command to start and enable service :

```
$ systemctl enable myservice.service
$ systemctl start myservice.service
```